# Calculating time with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having  `start_time` which is in string and `AM/PM` format, with a time interval, now my idea is to put start _time in while loop where it is being added with time interval and be in the loop until it becomes greater than current_time, I want to pull out next current time within this interval.

Let's suppose

```
start_time  => 10:00 AM
current_time => moment()
time_interval => 15 mins
```

> So if any user calls this function at 10:05 AM then I want output to be 10:15 AM, or any user calls this function at 12:33 PM so my output will be 12:45 PM and so on.

To achieve this I'm trying something like this:

```
nextDrawTime() {
    let moment = require('moment');
    let now = moment();
    let set_time = moment(now.get('date') + ' ' + this.start_time).get('time');
    while(set_time > moment) {
        set_time.add(this.time_interval, 'm');
    }
    return set_time.format('LT');
}
```

But somehow this is not working out. Help me out with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call moment.

```
while(set_time > moment())
```

Comment: I am unable to compare timings that is why my while loop is not working, even in your answer it is unable to enter while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
function nextDrawTime() {
    let now = moment();
    start_time = '10:00 AM';
    let set_time = moment( now.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + start_time).get('time');

    while( set_time < moment() ) {
        set_time.add(15, 'm');
    }
    return set_time.format('LT');
}
console.log(nextDrawTime());
</script>
```

`now.get('date')` just returns the int `11` - you need to create today as a full string then compare, also you need to check less than `<`

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's far more effective working with the Unix Timestamp.

```
var interval = 15 * 60; // interval in seconds = 15 minutes

var next15 = moment(((Math.floor(moment().unix() / interval) * interval) + interval) * 1000)

console.log(next15.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nextDrawTime(time, format = "LT", interval = 15) {
    const next = moment(time, format);
    const roundedMinute = Math.ceil(next.minute() / interval) * interval;
    return next
        .minutes(0)
        .seconds(0)
        .add(roundedMinute, "minutes")
        .format(format);
}

nextDrawTime(moment().format("LT"))

console.log("10:05 AM =>", nextDrawTime("10:05 AM"));
console.log("12:33 PM =>", nextDrawTime("12:33 PM"));
console.log("11:59 AM =>", nextDrawTime("11:59 AM"));
console.log("11:59 PM =>", nextDrawTime("11:59 PM"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Works for different time formats and intervals

```
nextDrawTime(
    "Tuesday, December 31th 2019, 11:59:59 pm", // Time
    "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a" // Format
    60, // Interval

) 
// Wednesday, January 1st 2020, 12:00:00 am
```